# Why does Xcode costs so much memory when building a project?

Tags: xcode, memory-management

I'm using Apple Silicon Mac (which using M1 chip CPU), and when I was building my project using Xcode 14.2 (14C18), the memory usage of Xcode is huge, sometimes I have to kill other apps to finish the building. That was terrible. Someone who knows how to solve this problem?

Every time I encounter the memory warning of my Mac, I have to restart my mac.

Comment: How much is "huge"? Does your Mac only have 8GB of memory? If so, development will indeed be painful, not just on Mac but on Linux and Windows too. And not just for Xcode, but for Java, node.js and many others too.

Comment: @Codo If I don't restart my mac, and working for a whole day, the memory usage of Xcode would be around 5-6GB while building project. My mac has 16GB memory. I don't know whether it's an optimizing way for m1 mac, to use more memory to upgrade cpu performance.